# Add/update element in already existing array in a MongoDB document

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I've a customer document with attributes array. I want to insert new attributes and update already existing ones.

**Already existing** "attributes" within the document:

```
[{
      key: "email",
      value: "abc@efg.com"
    }, {
      key: "name",
      value: "Somebody"
}]
```

I want to** add or update** within "attributes"

```
    [{
      key: "email",
      value: "new_email@efg.com"
    }, {
      key: "mobile",
      value: "1234567890"
    }]
```

So, **the result should be**:

```
[{
key: "email",
value: "new_email@efg.com"
},{
key: "name",
value: "Somebody"
},{
key: "mobile",
value: "1234567890"
}]
```

I achieved the result using below written code. But I want to **use only MongoDB to get the same result**.

```
const { attributes, uid } = req.body;
const customer: any = await getCustomer({ uid });
const oldAttributes = customer?.attributes.filter((attr: any) => !attributes.find((att: any) => att.key === attr.key));
const updatedAttributes = [...oldAttributes, ...attributes];
const response = await updateCustomer({ uid }, { $set: { attributes: updatedAttributes } } );
```

Comment: You are trying to make the update programmatically after you find which is not efficient and have identified that as an issue. Howver, without seeing `getCustomer` or `updateCustomer` code nobdy can provide you a specific answer. I suspect what you need to use is `findOneAndUpdate()`, are you using mongoose or Node native driver?

Answer (score 2):

Since using `upsert` would overwrite the old attributes with the new attributes, rather than updating just the attributes array, this would need a full pipeline, ending with a `merge` back into the collection.

Assuming a document like this:

```js
[
  {
    _id: 12345,
    attributes: [
      {
        key: "email",
        value: "abc@efg.com"
      },
      {
        key: "name",
        value: "Somebody"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Steps at a high-level:

1. Convert the array of `{key: "<key_name>", value: "<value>"}` to an object having `{<key_name>: <value>, ...}`

   - This assumes each key is unique with the array of `attributes`.
   - Otherwise, the last occurrence overwrites the first.
2. Merge it with the values provided by the user: so existing values get updated, new value get added, fields not provided remain.
3. Convert it back to an array of `{key: "<key_name>", value: "<value>"}`

User input would be required for the first `$match` step for the document `_id` and then for the `$mergeObjects` step where you add user provided values.

Notes:

- It's possible to use a `$let` or nested `"$set": { "attributes": ... }` but it feels cleaner and clearer as separate pipeline steps.
- If you know the attributes will always be only name, email, mobile, then you can change the object to array step with an explicit set/project with `[{"key": "name", "value": "$attribute.name}, {"key": "email", "value": "$attribute.value"}, ...]` in the `objecToArray` step not require the re-mapping of labels after that.
- For the final `merge`, I have put `whenNotMatched: "fail"` since you probably can't use this for records which don't already exist.
- Added an alternate playground using [`db.collection.update()`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) instead of aggregate. So the final `$merge` is not required. But you will need to add `{upsert: false, multi: false}` for the 3rd param; which finally becomes the same length/complexity as the original anyway.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      // whichever doc you're updating
      "_id": 12345
    }
  },
  {
    // unwrap the key value pairs to actual "key: value"
    "$set": {
      "attributes": {
        "$arrayToObject": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$attributes",
            "as": "i",
            "in": {
              k: "$$i.key",
              v: "$$i.value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // merge it with new/updated data
    "$set": {
      "attributes": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$attributes",
          {
            // this is where you add new field and set existing ones
            "email": "new_email@efg.com",
            "mobile": "1234567890"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // convert it back to an arry of [{"k": <k1>, v: <v1>}, {"k": k2, "v": <v2>}]
    "$set": {
      "attributes": {
        "$objectToArray": "$attributes"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // convert "k" --> "key" and "v" --> "value"
    "$set": {
      "attributes": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$attributes",
          "as": "e",
          "in": {
            "key": "$$e.k",
            "value": "$$e.v"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // write to the collection
    $merge: {
      into: "collection",
      on: "_id",
      whenMatched: "replace",
      whenNotMatched: "fail"
    }
  }
])
```

Result:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": 12345,
    "attributes": [
      {
        "key": "email",
        "value": "new_email@efg.com"
      },
      {
        "key": "name",
        "value": "Somebody"
      },
      {
        "key": "mobile",
        "value": "1234567890"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4t5-FmQDvwU)

[Alternate, with `collection.update()`](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2IlR7-XDuNa).

PS. I think [`$objectToArray`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) really needs some options for customising the label for the key and value.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `upsert: true` in `options` when you call `updateCustomer` as follows:

```
const options = { upsert: true };

const response = await updateCustomer({ uid }, { $set: { attributes: updatedAttributes } }, options );
```

You can refer to more at: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/write-operations/upsert/

Comment: Using `upsert` like this would not do the update for the elements in the array. It would overwrite the existing one with the new values, so the old/unchanged values would get removed.